# What are CMS_TEMPLATES in settings of a django app used for?

Tags: django, content-management-system

In a app i have seen

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_general.html', gettext('General template')),
    ('template_no_menu.html', gettext('Template without menu'))
)
```

Should i do anything specific with them such as add them in django admin cms??

Comment: This isn't anything to do with Django but will be some custom setting for one of the apps you are using.

Answer (score 0):

DjangoCMS makes use of these templates. These are used for creating the pages dynamically through the page settings of the DjangoCMS which sets the default layout of that page according to the selected template layout from your CMS_TEMPLATES lists.
Either these templates can be within your projects templates folder or apps template folder.

These settings are not required if you are not using DjangoCMS